# Detecting new permutations in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

In our DB we have one table that is the result of every permutation from three tables.

I'm trying to write a PHP script that will look at all of these tables as arrays and detect whether there is a missing permutation.

e.g.

```
$foo = array('one', 'two', NULL)
$bar = array('three', 'four', NULL)
$baz = array('five', 'six', NULL)

$permutations = array(
  array('one', 'three', 'five'),
  array('two', 'three', 'five'),
  array(NULL, 'three', 'five'),
  //etc
)

foreach $foo as $x
  foreach $bar as $y
    foreach $baz as $z
      $combo = array($x, $y, $z)
      if $combo is not in $permutations
         //generate sql to update db
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you have X tables that each have Y elements (??), then you'll have X^Y permutations if this is a "permutation with repetition." So, a quick smoke test would be making sure that `$permutations` length is the same as X^Y (or whatever the range of sets *should* be)...you can also do something like making sure that $permutations has only unique elements before doing the length check. This may be more efficient than having to check every single possible permutation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to retrieve each possible permutations with MySQL and using LEFT JOIN on the 4th table and testing if there is no match

If you have 3 tables t1, t2, t3 containing one column "value", and table t4 which is the "permutation" which contains three columns t1, t2 and t3, you can get the non existing "permutation" with the following query

```
SELECT t1.value v1, t2.value v2, t3.value v3
FROM t1, t2, t3
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t4.t1=v1 AND t4.t2=v2 AND t4.t3=v3
WHERE t4.t1 IS NULL;
```

You can adapt this query to match your database schema.

Comment: You should emulate a full outer join to get the answer in one query.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno exactly what you try to do but i suggest :

```
$foo = array('one', 'two', NULL);
$bar = array('three', 'four', NULL);
$baz = array('five', 'six', NULL);

$permutations = array(
  array('one', 'three', 'five'),
  array('two', 'three', 'five'),
  array(NULL, 'three', 'five'),
  //etc
);

$foobarbaz = array_merge($foo, $bar, $baz);
foreach($foobarbaz as $k){ 
  if(!in_array($k, $permutations) {
     $sql_trigger_start();
  }
}
```

A example who get this problem.
http://dannyherran.com/2011/06/finding-unique-array-combinations-with-php-permutations/

Comment: array_merge won't work. Not like this anyway. The $permutations array currently contains every possible combination of the $foo, $bar, and $baz arrays. However sometimes $foo, $bar, $baz arrays have new items added to them, meaning that the $permutations array no longer contains every combination. I need a way of testing every possible combination against the $permutations array and detect when it does not exist so I can generate an SQL statement. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes thanks you can solve your problem going to this link http://dannyherran.com/2011/06/finding-unique-array-combinations-with-php-permutations/